# Red Hat Fuse ESB Community vs Enterprise edition

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

This should be a simple 'google' ... but I have drawn a blank. I assume it must be out there somewhere, can anyone help me find it?

I need a simple comparison that tells me what is in and what is out of the Fuse ESB community edition vs the enterprise edition?

Here are some questions  :

- Is Red Hat Fuse is open source or commercial ?
- What's main differences between Fuse ESB Enterprise and Community Edition (Comparing Features)
- i downloaded jboss-fuse-full-6.2.0.redhat-133 from Red Hat Site and i cannot recognize it is  Edition version or Enterprise edition
- What if we use Community edition or Enterprise edition in Production usage ?
- i did research some tutorial about Fuse ESB only i found is Apache Camel and CXF tutorials(All these are creating soap services from bottom) : Can i deploy/ publish  existing (our SOAP service) to Fuse Management Console and Track and Monitor service's request and response ?
- Our company has been searching Open Source ESB based on our needs to use it in Production Environment (Then we chose Red Hat FUSE)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Red Hat software is open source.  You can download and use anything you can get from the 'free' distribution sites like https://developers.redhat.com.  (Fuse version 6.2 is very old, by the way.)

The difference is that you get professional support when you buy a support agreement.  Red Hat support only concerns the 'professional, product' versions of the software like 'Fuse'.  The 'community' versions like Camel are not supportable by Red Hat support.